# Why is x undefined?

Tags: matlab

Please help me get rid of the following error:

```
error: 'x' undefined near line 3 column 8
error: called from
conv_test at line 3 column 2
MAIN at line 17 column 1
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
error: called from
conv_test at line 3 column 2
MAIN at line 17 column 1
```

Inside of **MAIN.m** I simply call:

```
result_g_p1 = conv_test(@g_p1);
```

My **g_p1.m:**

```
function endpoint = g_p1(x)
    endpoint = -8/(x^3);
end
```

**conv_test.m**:

```
function conv_test_result = conv_test(g)
    if (g(x) > 1) && (g(x) < 0)    <--- Line 3
        conv_test_result = fprintf('Convergent Test Result: The function is monotonically convergent! \n');
    elseif (g(x) > -1) && (g(x) < 0)
        conv_test_result = fprintf('Convergent Test Result: The function is oscillatory convergent! \n');
    else (g(x) > 1)
        conv_test_result = fprintf('Convergent Test Result: The function is divergent! \n');
    end
end
```

I don't know why it says `x` is undefined because I clearly pass `g_p1` inside of `conv_test`.

Answer (score 1):

The function `g_p1` looks fine; however, in `conv_test_result`, you pass in a function and then evaluate that function for some variable `x` that is not shown to be defined. You need to give `x` a value in `conv_test_result` before evaluating `g(x)`.

Comment: Its value is defined in **g_p1** and that "endpoint" is being passed into conv_test as **x**.

Comment: In ``main`` you call ``conv_test`` with the parameter (the function ``g_p1``). Inside of ``conv_test_result`` that function is now called ``g``. On line 3 you try to evaluate ``g`` (that is, ``g_p1``) with the parameter ``x``, but you haven't yet assigned any value to ``x`` inside of ``conv_test``, so the program doesn't know what value to pass into ``g_p1``.